# MS symbol servers and Nuget symbol servers blocked

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to set up MS symbols server and NuGet Symbol server in Vs 2019,

but out security requires us to login for every connection (browser, window etc)

Does anyone know the servers being specifically hit so I can request to get them added to an exclusion list?

Comment: Did you face the issue with firewall or any other defense tools?

Comment: Work has zscalar set up to block each web connection till you authenticate. I need the names of the symbol servers to get them added to the exclusion list so VS can it them when needed